# How to fetch data and cache it until midnight

Tags: next.js, tanstackreact-query

I have a method which returns the count of users registered during last 24 hours. I want to call it only once a day, i.e. call it and cache results untill midnight. I'm using `tanstack-query` for data fetching and the app is written in NextJS. Is it possible?

Comment: _Next.js_ has a built-in property to cache the data for a specific time and after that time it will fetch a fresh copy of data from the server/api. see [Time-based Revalidation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#time-based-revalidation)

Comment: OK thank you! I guess that its not possible to do it with tanstack-query cache?